# form2 textbox to form1 datagridview with service-based database

Tags: c#, windows, winforms

I have Form1 with a DataGridView from service-based database that I created and a Customer Info Button. This button opens Form2 which is use to add another costumer.

Every information that I write in Form2 must show in Form1 DataGridView.

How do i do this? Please help me!

This is my `Form1` code:

```
namespace Icabales.Homer
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Database1Entities db1Entity = new Database1Entities();
            var myProducts = from p in db1Entity.Products
                             select p;
            cboProduct.DataSource = myProducts;
            cboProduct.DisplayMember = "ProductName";
            cboProduct.ValueMember = "ProductID";
            var myCostumers = from c in db1Entity.Costumers
                              select c;
            dgCostumer.DataSource = myCostumers;
            dgCostumer.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;
            txtStocks.DataBindings.Add("Text", myProducts, "StocksLeft");
            txtUnitPrice.DataBindings.Add("Text", myProducts, "Unitprice");
            txtCostumer.DataBindings.Add("Text", myCostumers, "CostumerName");
            dgCart.Columns.Add("ProductID", "ID");
            dgCart.Columns.Add("ProductName", "Item");
            dgCart.Columns.Add("Quantity", "Quantity");
            dgCart.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;                       
        } 

        private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {   
            dgCart.Rows.Add(cboProduct.SelectedValue, cboProduct.Text, txtQuantity.Text);
        }

            private void btnSaveOrder_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
            Database1Entities db1Entity = new Database1Entities();
            Order myOrder;
            foreach (DataGridViewRow r in dgCart.Rows)
        {
            if (r.Cells[0].Value != null) //check for each ProductID that is not Empty
            {
                myOrder = new Order(); // create new order for each item in the Cart that has Product ID
                myOrder.ProductID = Convert.ToInt32(r.Cells[0].Value.ToString()); // Product ID
                myOrder.Quantity = Convert.ToInt32(r.Cells[2].Value.ToString()); // Quantity
                myOrder.CostumerID = Convert.ToInt32(dgCostumer.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value); myOrder.OrderDate = DateTime.Now; //get current Date and Time
                db1Entity.Orders.AddObject(myOrder);
            }
        }
        db1Entity.SaveChanges();
        MessageBox.Show("Your Order has been saved!", "Order", MessageBoxButtons.OK,
        MessageBoxIcon.Information);
    }

    private void btnRemove_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewRow item in this.dgCart.SelectedRows)
        {
            dgCart.Rows.RemoveAt(item.Index);
        }
    }

    private void btnClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dgCart.Rows.Clear();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        new Form2().Show();
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        new Form3().Show();
    }
}
}
```

cant post image new member :(

Comment: Would it make sense to show the other form as a dialog form?

Comment: You can use the BindingSource for the data access and return to Form1 just reload the BindingSource. The way you are working is also possible to reload the DataSource performing one select the DataSource. But the way you're doing is not a good practice, you're encapsulating the entire data layer inside the constructor restricting your data source (var MyProducts) of the remaining class scope. See this links:
bit.ly/TCPMli and bit.ly/XPHS8c
I hope i helped.

Comment: Please see this question. [Open Form2 from Form1, close Form1 from Form2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2958912/open-form2-from-form1-close-form1-from-form2). It will give you an idea..